# Django No Mini matches the given query

Tags: python, django, url, http-status-code-404

I wrote a link-shortener app that takes a regular long url, and creates a 10 character alphanumeric string that it uses for the redirection with Django-1.5.1.
The redirection link from the generated string works fine with : `url(r'^(?P<short>\w+)/$', 'target'),` but for some reason when I try to access the other two views ( one to create a new short url and one to view all the links ) I get a 404 page saying "No Mini matches the given query." The puzzling thing is that everything works fine when I use `url(r'^$', 'new_link'),` or `url(r'^$', 'home'),`

here are the contents of my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('mini_url.views',
    url(r'^(?P<short>\w+)/$', 'target'),
    url(r'^new_link/$', 'new_link'),
    url(r'^home/$', 'home'),
)
```

and views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from mini_url.models import Mini
from mini_url.forms import MiniForm
import string, random

def generate(N):
    characters = string.letters + string.digits
    random_list = [random.choice(characters) for _ in xrange(N)]
    return ''.join(random_list)

def new_link(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MiniForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            create = True
            link = form.save(commit=False)
            short_url = generate(10)
            link.short_url = short_url
            link.save()
            link_string = "http://localhost:8000/m/%s/" % short_url

    else:
        form = MiniForm()

    return render(request, 'mini_url/new_link.html', locals())


def target(request, short):
    short_link = get_object_or_404(Mini, short_url = short)
    short_link.counter += 1
    short_link.save()
    return redirect(short_link.long_url)

def home(request):
    links = Mini.objects.order_by('counter')
    return render(request, 'mini_url/home.html', {'links':links})
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I can access the page to create a new url by mapping it to r'^$' in urlpatterns, and then creating one and adding it to the database there works fine: `>>> Mini.objects.get(short_url='8OA1Ys97rR')
<Mini: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987392/django-no-mini-matches-the-given-query>`, the problem is I can't acces the page if I want to go through r'^new_link/$'

Comment: change the order of the URLs. It will work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with your URL patterns. Change the order, and it will work fine.

Change order to:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('mini_url.views',
    url(r'^new_link/$', 'new_link'),
    url(r'^home/$', 'home'),
    url(r'^(?P<short>\w+)/$', 'target'),
)
```

Since your regex for url pattern match is `\w+`, when you do a `/home` or `/new_link`

Here, the URL target would match `url(r'^(?P<short>\w+)/$', 'target'),` first, and would call the view `target` with the parameter of `new_link` or `home`. Hence the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that both "new_link" and "home" match the definition for the short_link view, so they are being interpreted as calls to that page. You should move the short_link to the bottom, so it's only matched when none of the others do.